# How to convey with an URI what is content type of the resource?

Tags: url

I would like to use URIs to represent different files we can use in our system. But to know which module to use to parse it, it would be great if I could somehow encode what is content type of the resource to which it is pointing at, so that it can be given to a proper module for parsing.

I was thinking to maybe extend scheme part to convey this. For example `file+csv:///path/to/file` would point to a CSV file, while `file+caffe:///path/to/directory` would point to a directory with Caffe model and parameters. And so on. I have a limited set of types I want to support so this seems a reasonable way?

But is there some other standard way?

Comment: Have you considered using file extensions?  Probably the most traditional solution to this problem, at least.

Comment: Or look at content-type in the response?

Comment: They are pointers to local files, there is no content-type in response. Also, this would require me to first load the file, check content-type, and then pass content to a module. I have modules which accept URIs as inputs, not content itself (they are a bunch of  not very connected modules).

Comment: File extensions do not work for directory-based resources.

Comment: How does your system get to know which files are available and what type those files are? Can your modules deal with such non-standard extended schemes in the URIs passed to them?

Comment: Where is the knowledge about the content type of the file? Before you decide on a way to encode that knowledge, you should find out where this knowledge can be found. E.g. do the file names follow a naming convention? Does the user tell you about the file type? Or what?

Comment: So URI is being passed from a different service, which all share the same volume mounted. So we are trying to have a decoupled architecture. So one service creates as a file, saves it, and passes URI to the other service. Now the question is how should the other service would know to which internal module to pass it. Of course I could add this extra information as an extra message field, but I am curious if we could just use URI for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

URLs by themselves are very protocol-agnostic. They do not specify much more than a common syntax and basic semantics. An URL generally describes how to find something, but not what you'll find there.

It is the job of a particular protocol such as HTTP to indicate the content type. Some resources do not have a meaningful content type, for example `mailto:` URLs. The FTP protocol has no concept of MIME types, but merely distinguishes textual files, binary files, and directories (specified as a `;type=<typecode>` parameter in an FTP URL). Regarding file URLs, RFC 1738 *Uniform Resource Locators (URL)* notes:

> The file URL scheme is unusual in that it does not specify an Internet protocol or access method for such files; as such, its utility in network protocols between hosts is limited.

RFC 8089 *The "file" URI Scheme* concurs:

> The file URI scheme is not coupled with a specific protocol nor with a specific media type [RFC6838].

So most URL schemes do not allow you to include the content type in the URL, and there is no scheme-agnostic mechanism to do that.

You can of course develop your own non-standard URL scheme that consists of MIME type + transport. It would be best to not put the type into the scheme name: I'd consider a design such as `example:text/csv:file://path/to/file`.

Alternatively you could store the type in a query param of a file URL – except that a file URI syntax as defined by the RFC does not have query parameters. This also may lead to problems with some implementations on Windows systems. But this has the advantage that query params for file URLs are ignored by parsers that use the [WHATWG's generic URL parsing algorithm](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-parsing).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any tool that can handle this, but this does "convey" the information:

```
data:message/external-body;access-type=URL;URL="file:///path/to/directory",Content-Type:%20text/csv%0D%0AContent-Transfer-Encoding:%20binary%0D%0AContent-ID:%20<file:///path/to/directory>
```

A conformant application should, theoretically, when loading the [`data:`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) URI, recognize the [`message/external-body`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.2.3) type and transparently load the resource specified by the [URL access type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2017) and treat it as `text/csv`. Other headers can be included in the body, but note that `Content-ID` is mandatory and the default value of `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is `7bit`.

Comment: Is this some standard?

Comment: @Mitar Not in particular, but a combination of standards.

Comment: Care to link to those standards?

Comment: @Mitar Edited in.